# Boost Test entry/exit fixture with manual registration

Tags: c++, boost-test, fixture

I am using Boost 1.61 and I am working with the following type of Boost Test setup where I am manually registering tests:

```cpp
// testsuite.cpp
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using boost::unit_test::test_suite;

test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int, char* []) {
    test_suite* test = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("TestSuiteName");
    test->add(FooTest::suite());
    return test;
}

// foo.hpp
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using boost::unit_test::test_suite;

class FooTest {
public:
    static void testFoo1();
    static void testFoo2();
    static test_suite* suite();
}

// foo.cpp
#include <foo.hpp>

void FooTest::testFoo1() {
    // testFoo1 implementation
}
void FooTest::testFoo2() {
    // testFoo2 implementation
}

test_suite* FooTest::suite() {
    test_suite* suite = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("FooTest");
    suite->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&FooTest::testFoo1));
    suite->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&FooTest::testFoo2));
    return suite;
}
```

I would like to add an entry/exit fixture, as described [here](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/per_test_suite_fixture.html), to the FooTest test suite. The Boost Test documentation describes this feature in the context of automatically registered tests.

Can I use this entry/exit fixture feature with my setup where I am manually registering tests? If not, does anyone have a suggestion as to how I could mimic this behavior i.e. have an object constructed *once* on entry in to the FooTest test suite, available to all tests in the test suite and then destructed on exit from the FooTest suite?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902925/boost-test-case-and-suite-fixtures-in-manually-defined-suite-tree) but I could not find an answer that I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it is useful to someone, from looking in some of the Boost Test source files, I came up with the following that seems to meet my requirements i.e. using an entry/exit fixture with manual registration.

```
// testsuite.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using boost::unit_test::test_suite;

test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int, char*[]) {
    test_suite* test = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("TestSuiteName");
    test->add(FooTest::suite());
    return test;
}

// bar.hpp (The class to be tested)
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}

    int x_;
    int y_;
};

// foo.hpp
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
using boost::unit_test::test_suite;

class FooTest {
public:
    static void testFoo1();
    static void testFoo2();
    static test_suite* suite();
};

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "bar.hpp"

#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

#include <vector>

using boost::unit_test::test_unit_fixture_ptr;
using std::vector;

namespace {
boost::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;

void setup() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Creating Bar Instance");
    bar = boost::make_shared<Bar>(1, 2);
}

void teardown() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("Destroying Bar Instance");
    bar.reset();
}
}

void FooTest::testFoo1() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("In testFoo1");
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(bar->x_ == 1, "Checking x_");
}
void FooTest::testFoo2() {
    BOOST_TEST_MESSAGE("In testFoo2");
    BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(bar->y_ == 2, "Checking y_");
}

test_suite* FooTest::suite() {
    test_suite* suite = BOOST_TEST_SUITE("FooTest");

    // Manually add an entry/exit fixture to the test suite
    vector<test_unit_fixture_ptr> fixtures {
        boost::make_shared<boost::unit_test::function_based_fixture>(setup, teardown)};
    suite->p_fixtures.set(fixtures);

    suite->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&FooTest::testFoo1));
    suite->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&FooTest::testFoo2));
    return suite;
}
```

This code gives the following output when run with `log_level=message`

```
 Running 2 test cases...
 Creating Bar Instance
 In testFoo1
 In testFoo2
 Destroying Bar Instance

 *** No errors detected
```

Let me know if you think there are flaws with this approach or if you feel there is a better method for achieving what I want.

Comment: Would you not want to have `Bar` instances being created and destroyed for every test? This way your test do not seem to be run in isolation.

Comment: Well today, I do not see any valid reason to use manual test registration. I also do believe that test registration can be mixed inside one test module: manual + automatic should be able to coexist within the test module. In your case, you may use automatic registration for the `FooTest` class (also `test_unit_fixture_ptr` and `p_fixtures` are not officially documented and should be private API).